# Is this book good for learning math for college physics?

Tags: self-learning, book-recommendation, education, learning

The book Comprehensive Engineering Mathematics, by John Bird seems to be good also not only for engineering but also for university physics. Since as far as I can see it is applied mathematics. And it covers from elementary arithmetic to very advanced topics like Fourier series.
I wonder if it is adequate to study it to prepare me for physics in college, at least as essential mathematics to be able to understand physics at that level and in passing review elementary topics and thus have a strong foundation.
And I ask specifically of this book, because there are other books that are mathematics for physics but I find that they have a pace that I can not follow, since they assume that you already know many things, and that you have no gaps of anything, and with this one I feel more comfortable.

Here I leave the link to the book, in case, whoever is so kind to answer, take a look at it:
http://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=8094DDC0DBBCFBCBB0857E03646346F3

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Terms like "university physics" and "elementary topics" are not very informative here, where people from dozens of countries participate, at a level from before high school to professional researcher. This could mean anything from non-calculus based general physics (e.g. [this](https://catalog.nwfsc.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=19&coid=21190)) to standard undergraduate physics major courses. You need to give some more context or detail about the level of physics you want preparation for.

Comment: "I ask specifically of this book, because there are other books that are mathematics for physics but I find that they have a pace that I can not follow..." : I consider this the most important statement in your posting.  Finding the right book for you makes all of the difference.  Hopefully, the book will include exercises for you to solve, since most of the *learning* (AKA developing fluency) is caused by tackling the exercises.  ...see next comment

Comment: Even if the book (or some other book that you choose that you are **totally comfortable** with) proves inadequate, you can always use that book as a stepping stone.  That is, I am suggesting that after you fully complete an *easier* book, including all of its exercises, I strongly suspect that you will then **actually be comfortable** with the fast paced books that you were originally uncomfortable with.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro 
Apologies. By "university physics" I mean calculus-based physics, standard undergraduate physics. By "elementary subjects" I mean arithmetic, algebra, trigonometry.... I want preparation for standard undergraduate physics.

Comment: During roughly the middle third of the 20th century, as electrical engineering was becoming more mainstream (especially around the time of WW II) there were a lot of books written for electrical engineering students that might be worth looking at to see if they appear to have what you want. A couple from my bookshelves are [**Mathematics for Electricians and Radiomen**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000BFXW5Y) by Nelson Magor Cooke (1942) and [**Mathematics for Science and Engineering**](https://ur.booksc.me/book/2112130/a99288) by Philip Langdon Alger (1957). **(continued)**

Comment: Looking at archive.org, [here are some books by Nelson M. Cooke](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Cooke%2Cnelson%22) and [books with "mathematics" and "electronics" in their title](https://archive.org/search.php?query=title%3A%28mathematics%20electronics%29) and [books with "mathematics" and "electricians" in their title](https://archive.org/search.php?query=title%3A%28mathematics%20electricians%29), and you get the idea. You can modify the URL's directly by changing the search words. For example, along with "mathematics" try "technicians", "radio", "statics", "general", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally an "engineering mathematics" text is much the same thing as a "physics mathematics" text. There is sometimes more emphasis on something like vectors in physics books but the difference is minimal and physics courses may well use an engineering book.

The book you've pointed to seems to start from what would be regarded as school-level mathematics, go through things like trigonometry, and build up to calculus and statistics.

Working through this book will be an excellent preparation for study in physics. However, it's not greatly suitable if you want to be a mathematician.

Comment: And if I wanted to study for an undergraduate degree in mathematics, what book or books analogous to this one would be recommended? So that like this one, it would cover elementary to very advanced topics.

Comment: Actually, my real goal is to go into theoretical physics. And I have known that to become a good theoretical physicist, you need to be a good mathematician.

Comment: I think I look confused. But I'm alone in this, and I'm figuring out the things I'm interested in, how to learn them, where to go, what to do and what not to do. I'm even learning English...

Comment: I have gaps in my mathematical knowledge, and this book seemed perfect because it covers elementary to complex topics.

Comment: If you have more questions then ask another question, don't ask questions in the comments.